# Массив с русскими буквами не работает в Visual Studio 2017 на английской версии Windows 10

Tags: c, массивы, visual-studio-2017

**Проблема:** Массив с буквами кириллицы приводит к компиляции с фатальными ошибками. (Если снять комментарий с строки массива russian2).
**Вопрос:** Почему так происходит?
(Кодировка: Windows-1251)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char english[] = { "English: string literal work" };
    char russian[] = { "Русский: строковой литерал работает" };
    char english2[] = { 'I', 't', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'k', '\0' };
    //char russian2[] = { 'Н','е',' ','р','а','б','о','т','а','е','т','\0'};

    printf("%s\n", english);
    printf("%s\n", english2);
    printf("%s\n", russian);
    //printf("%s\n", russian2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: С какими ошибками? скомпилировал VC++ 2017 - без проблем, скомпилировалось, вывело текст...

Comment: @Harry Действительно на русскоязычной версии Visual Studio работает. У меня английская версия, и на ней не работает такой фрагмент кода: `char rus[] = { 'Н','е',' ','р','а','б','о','т','а','е','т','\0'};` Понять почему не могу. При этом когда навожу курсор на какой-либо элемент (кириллический символ) в массиве rus[ ] то он думает что символ из UTF-8. Когда навожу курсор на строковой литерал с русскими словами, то он показывает как ASCII, т.е. верно.

Comment: _Коды ошибок:_ **C3688** invalid literal suffix '','; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator "", 
**C2059** syntax error: 'user-defined literal', **С2015** too many characters in constant, **C2018** unknown character '0x27', **C2018** unknown character '0x2c'

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); char ch = 'Ф'; char rus[] = { ch,'\0' };` для этого такие ошибки: Warning **C4305** 'initializing': truncation from 'int' to 'char' (line 3),  **C4309** 'initializing': truncation of constant value (line 3), **C2001** newline in constant (line 2)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Проблема была в windows 10: Панель управления - Часы и регион - Региональные стандарты - Дополнительно - Изменить язык системы - Убрать галочку с Использовать Юникод для поддержки языка во всем мире[image: Вот тот самый checkbox]

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Два дня возился)